# Object is not a function error, when putting array in new component

Tags: reactjs

I have an react app, where I have an array of some ski days, with some information about some ski trips:

```js
    allSkiDays:[
      {
        resort: "Squaw Valley",
        date: new Date("12/24/2018"),
        powder: true,
        backcountry: false
      },
      {
        resort: "Val Thorens",
        date: new Date("12/22/2018"),
        powder: true,
        backcountry: true
      },
      {
      resort: "Val Desire",
      date: new Date("5/15/2018"),
      powder: false,
      backcountry: true
      },
      {
      resort: "Squaw Valley",
      date: new Date("1/18/2018"),
      powder: true,
      backcountry: false
      }
    ]
}
```

initially, they were placed in my App.js (main file), I declared them with a component called SkiDaysList

like such :

```js
<SkiDaysList ={(array inserted here)} />
```

I have now created a new component called classCreator, where I want to store the array instead, for better code practice:

```js
export const classCreator = createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return { (array put here)

  render() {
return (
  <div className="classCreator">
  </div>
)
  }
```

but now i get this error:

```js
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
```

on this line

```js
export const classCreator = createClass({
```

Edit: Here is my entire classCreator component:

```js
import {createClass} from 'react';
```

import React, { Component}  from 'react';

```js
 export const classCreator = createClass({
  getInitialState(){
 return {
   allSkiDays:[
      {
        resort: "Squaw Valley",
        date: new Date("12/24/2018"),
        powder: true,
        backcountry: false
      },
      {
        resort: "Val Thorens",
        date: new Date("12/22/2018"),
        powder: true,
        backcountry: true
      },
      {
      resort: "Val Desire",
      date: new Date("5/15/2018"),
      powder: false,
      backcountry: true
      },
      {
      resort: "Squaw Valley",
      date: new Date("1/18/2018"),
      powder: true,
      backcountry: false
      }
    ]
  }
},

  render() {
 return (
   <div className="classCreator">
   </div>
   )
 }


})
```

Comment: Could you please include your entire `classCreator` component?

Comment: I have edited the code

Comment: should not it be [`createReactClass`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html) ? Your react version?

Comment: @Arup would that be better code practice?

Comment: Why don't you use ES6 way to define react class?

Comment: What is your version of react?

Comment: if i delete the seond classCreator so it just says export const classCreator = ({
  getInitialState(){.... it does not give any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem that `createClass` is still part of the React package after React v15.5.0.

You should import it from its own package `var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');`
 as described [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html#migrating-from-reactcreateclass)

Comment: I think this would work but i already have an import statement, where i declare the same thing at the top,